# Could not edit the server file in Adobe Bracket. No program error, just hang

Tags: file, server, edit, freeze, adobe-brackets

I have a problem with edit the file placed in the server by Adobe Brackets. On my Notepad++ I used the NppFTP plugin but now I would like to edit the files via Bracket. I installed 'Brackets Website Admin' plugin... I filled the settings like in the print screen:
[image: server settings]

I can see all file names but I cannot edit it.

[image: steps]

The program shows me the info that is trying to connect to the server. My question is if this is possible to edit them 'live' on the server like I can with NppFTP on Notepad++ ?

I have tried also with 'eqFTP' but it did not even show me files from the server.

Answer (score 0):

1 Get the latest version of the [plugin](https://s3.amazonaws.com/extend.brackets/brackets-website-admin/brackets-website-admin-0.0.8.zip)
2 Ensure project folder is not write protected
3 Give Brackets ADMIN rights